# Pymysql query throwing error when I add column with type varchar(100)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am new to using pymysql and SQL:

I have the following code which will run:

```
SQLquery = "CREATE TABLE sch_test4(id int, case_id varchar(40), procedure_date DATETIME, provider varchar(50));"
cursor.execute(SQLquery)
```

But when I add one more column, it will error:

```
SQLquery = "CREATE TABLE sch_test4(id int, case_id varchar(40), procedure_date DATETIME, procedure varchar(100), provider varchar(50));"
cursor.execute(SQLquery)
```

Why is adding procedure varchar(100) throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

`procedure` is a SQL keyword used to create user-defined procedures.

I would suggest giving the column a different name, such as `procedure_name`.